# Binding alias-named column to gridview in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, gridview, .net-3.5, bind

I am using .Net 3.5. I have a site that I have been using gridview controls on. Basically, it is a standard gridview, but with AutoGenerateColumns turned off in favor of creating our own columns via ItemTemplate. Here is an example of one of our custom columns:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Physician" ItemStyle-Width="70px" HeaderStyle-Width="70">
    <ItemTemplate>                            
        <asp:Label ID="lblPhysician" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LastName") %>' ></asp:Label>                            
    </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

In code behind, I fill a datatable based on an SQL query, and set it as the gridview datasource, and the label is normally populated based on the Bind function seen above during Postback. However, I have a SQL query that utilizes Alias names now. The query is rather large but here is an example:

```
SELECT LastName, COUNT(Case WHEN <condition> THEN 1 END) AS ABC 
FROM tablename WHERE <condition> Group By LastName
```

The problem is that I cannot use the Bind command on ABC as I use it for LastName. Nothing shows up in the gridview except LastName, even though data is returned for the alias columns. If I set AutoGenerateColumns to true, the gridview is binded with all the correct data, but this is not the way we need the page to work. What am I missing that is not allowing me to bind a column value manually to a control via it's alias name?

Thanks, and let me know if further clarification is needed!

Comment: What are you doing with this column?  Displaying, using it to show/hide, etc?

Comment: I just simply want to display the result of the aliased count. I get no errors but no data shows up either.

Answer (score 0):

You can grab it from the row on data bound; add an event handler, an in that handler do:

```
.. Grid_RowDataBound(..)
{
   var abc = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "ABC")
   if (abc == null)
      ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblPhysician")).Visible = false;
}
```

There may be some syntaxes that are off but the gist is that you can extract the field from the data item, and do something with it programmably.

You could also bind it in the item template using a hidden field, or stick it in the DataKeys collection too.

Comment: This isn't working, I get a null value back from DataBinder.Eval every time. From the RowDataBound event in the gridview..

Dim abc As DataBinder = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ABC")

Comment: I have also tried dropping As DataBinder from the statement above and still Nothing is returned.

Comment: Errr, sorry, I mixed my code, it would be:  var abc As Object = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ABC"), edited above.  DataBinder.Eval uses reflection to extract the property value, and therefore it would return an object.

Comment: This doesn't solve my issue, I am not getting error, it is just DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ABC") returns Nothing. But again, if I AutoGenerate columns, I get a column named ABC and values.

Comment: Use intellisense and mouse over e.Item.DataItem, do you see the field there, and is it the correct type?  Also, if you have it as DataBinder.Eval(..) as X, and X is the incorrect type, this will always return null because as returns null if the types don't match up.

Comment: e.Row.DataItem itself is Nothing as well when I mouse over it. I don't get it, I know I'm not typing the column name incorrectly, it is simple. This has worked for about 10 other gridviews in the site except for these aliases.

Comment: For all rows bound to the grid, or for the first one only, or...?  In RowDataBound, e.Item.DataItem should be present, as it always has worked for me.  The only other option I know of is to use the datakeys, or a hidden field, and extract it from there.  If you use DataKeys, you can easily get this in RowDataBound.